# WSO2 IS 5.11.0/APIM 4.1.0- oauth2/revoke API not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

**Here are the steps followed to revoke an Access Token.**

1. Deploy and published the API on APIM.
2. Generate an access token from APIM

`curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>&scope=openid" -H "Authorization: Basic <BASE64 ENCODED CONSUMER_KEY:CONSUMER_SECRET>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://<GATEWAY_HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/oauth2/token`

3. Success fully invoke the APIs by setting access token to Authorization header
   [image]
4. Revoke the access token by calling the following API by passing the access token and got success

`curl -k -v -d "token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_TO_BE_REVOKED>" -H "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded (clientId:clientSecret)>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke`

[image]
5. **Still the access toke is active and am able to access the published APIs with the access token**

- **Why the access token still active after revoke?**
- **Is there any way to check /oauth2/revok APIs is working or not?**
- **Is there any configuration to setup the /oauth2/revoke APIs to revoke the access token?**
  .

**Environment**

- **WSO2 IS 5.11.0**
- **WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0**

Comment: Are you generating the token using IS? If so, you need to check whether it is running on port 9443. Usually when both servers are run, the IS should be running with a port offset if APIM is running on 9443.

Comment: Yes we are generating the access token using IS

Comment: Yes we are generating the access token using IS, and IS is running on 9443. we are able to invoke the oauth2/revok API successfully but the access token is still active. The revoke apis not invalidating the access toke after revoke. Can you suggested is there anything i missed.

Comment: have you been able to fix this issue? I have WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 and having the same behaviour with /revoke endpoint and also when trying to refresh token

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you missed adding the following revocation event listener to the IS node.

```
# Event Listener configurations
[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1

[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://[control-plane-host]:[port]/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"
```

Can you add this to the IS node pointing the APIM control plane? Once the token is revoked, this event listener will send the details to the API Manager via the notification_endpoint and the Gateway will update its revoked tokens list.

Comment: The above configuration is already present in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` we followed the below [link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#step-4-configure-wso2-is-with-wso2-api-m) Step 4 - Configure WSO2 IS with WSO2 API-M. Still the revoke apis not invalidating the access toke after revoke

Comment: **Couple of observations with /oauth2/revoke API** - Before invoking the /oauth2/revoke, verified the below oauth2 APIs by passing the access token and able to get the expected response as the token is active. `https://localhost:9444/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid`
`https://localhost:9444/oauth2/introspect` - After invoking the /oauth2/revoke API,verified the above oauth2 APIs by passing the access token and getting error response as the token is inactive. **The access token is still active when we try to access the published APIs.**  **Why the access token active while accessing APIs?**

Comment: how is your deployment configured? All in one or distributed?

Comment: My deployment configuration is all in one

Comment: **any solution for this issue?** can you plz suggest is there any configuration missed

Comment: @hareesh have you been able to fix this issue? I have WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 and having the same behaviour with /revoke endpoint and also when trying to refresh token